Roman enumerate numbers stick out size of table cell. How to keep in cell?
I'm making a legal document, using an enumitem to number clauses, in the first clause I want a table of definitions. For some reason this combination causes another itemize with roman numerals to stick out the left hand side of the table cell a bit. How can I fix this?
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Definitions and Interpretation
    %\item \label{clause:defandinterp} \textbf{Definitions and Interpretation}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Definitions and Interpretation}\listhr
    \begin{itemize}
            \item In this Agreement, the following expressions have the following meanings:
\noindent\begin{longtable}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
Affiliate                         & 
such specified person and for the purposes of this definition, control shall mean:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item the ownership of more than fifty percent (50\%) of voting securities of; or
    \item the ability to elect a majority of the directors of; or
    \item the exercise of management control over and/or the exercise of a dominant influence upon,
\end{enumerate}
a person, whether through contract, constitutional documents or otherwise;\\
\end{longtable}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


It's also worth adding that in my real document, rather than this MWE the problem is much worse:


Probably unrelated, but a table with .3\textwidth and .7\textwidth is too large, you are surely getting a warning about that. You must consider also the column separation.

The sum of the column widths and padding around columns is bigger than the textwidth. Nothing to do with the list. The normal text also goes into the margin.

I've updated the example to make the table narrower, and added a line to the screenshot to highlight the issue. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and I'd be interested to know the correct way to make a table the width of the page though.

@campa I updated to remove the width issue

What is your preferred solution, keep the roman numerals right-aligned (as they are now) but increase the indent so the wider ones fit, or left-align the numerals?

@Marijn thanks, I think left align the numerals would be best for me.

In that case \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),align=left] solves the issue of the sticking out labels, however (iii) pushes the first line a bit inwards in that case.

@Marijn, thanks, but yes, the line does get moved, and in my real document the effect is more noticeable.

Possibly labelsep=* would solve this.

@Marijn, I'm using enumitem, and I have just found that leftmargin=* seems to solve the problem.

Using leftmargin=* seems to solve the problem
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Definitions and Interpretation
    %\item \label{clause:defandinterp} \textbf{Definitions and Interpretation}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Definitions and Interpretation}\listhr
    \begin{itemize}
            \item In this Agreement, the following expressions have the following meanings:
\noindent\begin{longtable}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
Affiliate                         & 
such specified person and for the purposes of this definition, control shall mean:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),leftmargin=*]
    \item the ownership of more than fifty percent (50\%) of voting securities of; or
    \item the ability to elect a majority of the directors of; or
    \item the exercise of management control over and/or the exercise of a dominant influence upon,
\end{enumerate}
a person, whether through contract, constitutional documents or otherwise;\\
\end{longtable}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


